# Mocha testing: 'TypeError: undefined not a function' at Test.serverAddress

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, express, mocha.js

I have the following test:

```
describe('Testing the GET methods', function() {
    it('Should be able to get the list of articles', function(done) {
      // Create a SuperTest request
      request(app).get('/api/articles/')
          .set('Accept', 'application/json')
          .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
          .expect(200)
          .end(function(err, res) {
              res.body.should.be.an.Array.and.have.lengthOf(1);
              res.body[0].should.have.property('title', article.title);
              res.body[0].should.have.property('content', article.content);

              done();
      });
    });

    it('Should be able to get the specific article', function(done) {
      // Create a SuperTest request
      request(app).get('/api/articles/' + article.id)
          .set('Accept', 'application/json')
          .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
          .expect(200)
          .end(function(err, res) {
              res.body.should.be.an.Object.and.have.property('title', article.title);
              res.body.should.have.property('content', article.content);

              done();
      });
    });
  });
```

Which produces this following error:
[image]

any ideas what might be the issue? I have all dependencies checked and installed and required.

**EDIT:**

The reason this happens is this: https://github.com/Oreqizer/mean-book/blob/master/server.js - lines 11 to 18.

My tests start BEFORE the app connects to the db. I noticed this by console.logging 'app', as well as noticing that
`Server running at http://localhost:3000/`
gets logged at different times during the first test.

How do I make mocha wait for the app to be defined before running the tests?

Comment: Where did you define `app`

Comment: https://github.com/Oreqizer/mean-book/blob/master/app/tests/articles.server.controller.tests.js here. you can check the whole source if it helps

Comment: When you look at line 55 of the first file mentioned in the call stack (ending in supertest\lib'test.js), does it read: `var addr = app.address();`?

Comment: yes. i also found the core of the problem, but not the solution yet. check the edit

Answer (score 2):

OK so it goes like this:

newer version of 'mongoose' causes express not to have a defined 'db' connection before i do `var app = express(db);` . However, if I add the code that goes:

```
db.connection.on('connected', callback);
```

where in the callback I define `app` , the test gets executed without app being defined.

I really don't know how to fix this besides having two different versions, one for test environment and one for development/production.